# How should this seemingly mysterious crash report from 4.1 be interpreted?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I'm getting a lot of complaints from people using 4.1 about my app crashing.  I was finally able to track down a device with 4.1 and get the crash logs from it (by the way, is there a way that I can use the simulator with 4.1?) and I'm not sure how I can interpret them.  I'm thinking the culprit may be AdWhirl, but I can't confirm this because the crash log doesn't mention it.  Here's the log:

```
Incident Identifier: D63B6947-B553-4816-BFF3-451105DF6AC1
CrashReporter Key:   e48b7e0079de90291849ebebfa2c4d2b3533593c
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         TruxMapFree [795]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/51E80AC4-C5FF-4D3B-95CE-A2F5A96FBF85/TruxMapFree.app/TruxMapFree
Identifier:      TruxMapFree
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-02-01 11:44:57.883 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   TruxMapFree                   0x0003d196 0x1000 + 246166
1   TruxMapFree                   0x000463ae 0x1000 + 283566
2   TruxMapFree                   0x000468ca 0x1000 + 284874
3   CoreFoundation                0x0003e2e4 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
4   Foundation                    0x0002081e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 262
5   CoreFoundation                0x00055f1e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
6   CoreFoundation                0x00027ba0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
7   CoreFoundation                0x00027444 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
8   CoreFoundation                0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
9   CoreFoundation                0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
10  GraphicsServices              0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
11  GraphicsServices              0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
12  UIKit                         0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
13  UIKit                         0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
14  TruxMapFree                   0x00003a4a 0x1000 + 10826
15  TruxMapFree                   0x00003a14 0x1000 + 10772

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x000d6b6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x000d65bc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib             0x000d675c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a67a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                       0x000024e2 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
7   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                    0x0002d686 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                    0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                    0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib             0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00025060 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                0x0005edfc __CFSocketManager + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   Foundation                    0x000eb1ec DYLD-STUB$$CFURLRequestGetURL + 0
1   Foundation                    0x0002dab2 -[NSURLRequest URL] + 18
2   Foundation                    0x0002d990 createCFRequest + 144
3   Foundation                    0x000aed5e +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 30
4   AppSupport                    0x00015c5e downloadDictionary + 122
5   AppSupport                    0x00015d5c -[PEPServiceConfiguration _updateDefaults:] + 76
6   Foundation                    0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
7   Foundation                    0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
8   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
9   libSystem.B.dylib             0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x004ade00    r1: 0x3303ae3b      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x004aef20    r5: 0x0017dd8d      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fffea2c
    r8: 0x004ad560    r9: 0x2fffe8e4     r10: 0x0017e45f     r11: 0x0017e453
    ip: 0x00000000    sp: 0x2fffea14      lr: 0x0003d181      pc: 0x0003d196
  cpsr: 0x600f0030

Binary Images:
........
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this, but I'll have a crack anyway because it's interesting :-)

My guess would be that thread 8 or more likely thread 3 (mach_msg_trap?) triggered some call back to the app which then tried to perform a selector on a nil object.

Just a wild guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an HTTP request is hitting your delegate when it returns from the server and is interacting with an object that has been deallocated (or set to nil) already. Trying to interact with deallocated objects is a main cause for your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.